# Access Environmental Variables with SaltStack Grains

Tags: python, salt-stack

I would like to know how to correctly access `Environmental Variables` with `SaltStack Grains`.

I have been following the [documentation](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/grains.html) but have been unable to get it working.  Here is the code that I have:

*/srv/salt/_grains/env_vars.py*

```
import os

def env_vars():
    return {'T17_SECRET_KEY': os.environ.get('T17_SECRET_KEY','')}
```

I then run `salt '*' saltutil.sync_grains`

And I get this response:

```
salt:
    - grains.env_vars
```

But when I run `salt '*' grains.items` it shows:

```
salt:
    ----------
    SSDs:
    T17_SECRET_KEY:
    # other vars ...
```

So the key is there, but the value is not.  When I run `os.environ.get('T17_SECRET_KEY','')` from the Python Command Line, the value is there.

What could be causing this?

**EDIT**

I have changed this:

*/srv/salt/_grains/env_vars.py*

```
from salt.modules import environ

def env_vars():
    return {'T17_SECRET_KEY': environ.get('T17_SECRET_KEY','')}
```

When I execute this function from the Python Command line, it returns the Key:Value, but still when running `salt '*' saltutil.sync_grains` and `salt '*' grains.items` I cannot see the Value, only the Key.

I even ran `salt '*' state.highstate` to reload everything.

Is this possibly being caused by some other configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.environ` accesses the process environment of the (random) Salt minion which happens to execute your code; if you want to access the environment of the current salt process, you need to use this module instead: [`salt.modules.environ`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.environ.html#module-salt.modules.environ)

The reason for this is that salt can run your code on any of a number of computers. The environment will probably be different for each of them. So unless you can make sure that your code is running on a certain minion and the environment on that minion is correct, your code can't work.

The module `salt.modules.environ` gives you access to the virtual process environment which salt builds when you submit a command.

To properly access the `salt.modules.environ` use the `salt.states.environ` by adding the following files:

*/srv/salt/_grains/env_vars.py*

```
from salt.modules import environ

def env_vars():
    return {'T17_SECRET_KEY': environ.get('T17_SECRET_KEY','')}
```

*/srv/salt/environ/init.sls*

```
T17_SECRET_KEY:
    environ.setenv:
        - name: T17_SECRET_KEY
        - value: <secret_key_value_here>
        - update_minion: True
```

Then run this to sync the newly added environmental variable:

```
salt '*' state.sls environ

salt '*' saltutil.sync_grains
```

To verify, this code can be ran:

```
salt '*' grains.get T17_SECRET_KEY
```

Comment: @Aaron_Digulla can you see my edit above?  I changed the function but am still unable to access the environmental variable's value.  Thank you.

Comment: How do you set `T17_SECRET_KEY` and where do you do it? Do you see the correct value when you do `echo $T17_SECRET_KEY`?

Comment: @Aaron_Digulla I added my working solution to your answer.  Thank you for your help with this.  I didn't know about `salt.modules.environ` and would not have known to use that. Thanks.